# Huge Problems with google's REST API : No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header

Tags: javascript, rest, api, google-maps, cors

I'm trying to use Google's directions API which gives a JSON response for a small route optimization application. I have worked with the google maps javascript API before and it was super easy to work with and well documented. The problem is, that i need more waypoints for my application and the javascript API only supports 8 with origin and destination. The directions API support 23 which would be enough. But I got the well know error that has been discussed here a lot:

**XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Adelaide,SA&destination=Adelaide,SA. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.**

But i can't get it to work. It doesn't matter what I try.

1. I've tried it with CORS as Google recommended:
   https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/cors.
   On this Page they link to a tutorial where you can configure your CORS request but I could not get it to work. Their own sample there doesn't even work.(Click Run Sample Button about a third in the page)
2. I've tried different JSONP requests with AJAX and JQuery that i found here on this site but google doesn't explicitly support JSONP requests. So I always get the error:
   **json?origin=Adelaide,SA&destination=Adelaide,SA&callback=jQuery3110281…*1479802069198&*…:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :**
   Thats because it expects a jsonp response but gets a normal json response.
3. I have also tried some libraries like p5.js but sadly it did not work.
4. Somewhere here i have read that there can be problems with a strict firewall and the request headers, so i tried it under different circumstances and locations but it didnt work either.

I can't really paste all my different code samples in here because I have tried so many things that it would be too long.(And these are all the samples i found on this site and other forums)

Also to note is that I have the HTML page located locally in a folder from where the javascript calls the API. I have read here somewhere that there can be Problems with CORS support when you open the HTML page from file:///C:/user/....mySite.html

I'm not an expert in Web development and after 2 days of trying I dont know what to do or what else to try. So my question is:

- Is what Im trying to do even possible(Calling the API from my local file)?
- If no, is there be a different approach?
- And If there is a way how can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The workaround is to create an intermediate server to proxy your requests to Google servers. You cannot execute them directly from client side code because of the Self-Origin Policy mentioned in your question.

So your application should send requests to intermediate server, intermediate server should send Directions API requests to Google and pass back all responses to your application.

Although, I wonder why you think the limit is 8 waypoints, the documentation says it's 23.

> Use of the Directions service with the Standard Plan
>
> 2,500 free requests per day, calculated as the sum of client-side and server-side queries; enable billing to access higher daily quotas, billed at $0.50 USD / 1000 additional requests, up to 100,000 requests daily.
> **Up to 23 waypoints per request, plus the origin and destination.**
> 50 requests per second, calculated as the sum of client-side and server-side queries.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions

Comment: Thanks thats what im doing right now and it works just fine. At the moment im using a free Proxy for development and testing. But one thing that is really really weird, when i click your link it says exactly what you posted. Except that theres only 8 for me. When i scroll down to Usage limits and policies the Standard plan has only 8 for me.

Comment: Do you apply an API key in Maps JavaScript API call? I suspect the 8 waypoint limit is for the keyless access.